# Click event on angular table elements, directing it to 2nd URL composed of selected element's ID

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-click

Each element in angular table should be triggered I mean clickable, i.e. when clicked on any element of table, it should take its ID as the basis of new search element and should direct to that URL id of clicked element.
Below is the json data of initial URL. It has ID which I am not displaying in my angular table.

```
{
  "emp": [
    {
      "BNK": "Rock",
      "GP1": [
        "92333"
      ]
    },
    {
      "BNK": "Jack",
      "GP1": [
        "923434",
        "928998"
        ]
    }
  ],
"status": "ok"
}
```

1)I want to click on say "BNK": "Rock"(which will be in angular table format), then it should direct to other URL(http://api.abc.com/1.1/**GetGP2?GP1=92333**&uid=api-key), which is searching for selected elements **ID** json data listed below and display that particular ID desription table given below

```
    {
      "emp": [
        {
          "BNK": "Jemmy XL",
          "DF": "24",
          "GP2": [
            "9233301"
          ]
        },
        {
          "BNK": "Geremy",
          "DF": "GEL",
          "GP2": [
            "9233302"
          ]
        }

 var countryApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.enteredValue = "*";
  $scope.targetUrl = 'url';
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.enteredValue = '';
  };
  $scope.doIt = function() {
    $scope.targetUrl = 'http://api.abc.com/GetGPs?**search=oxy**&uid=api-key';
    $http.get( $scope.targetUrl )
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.dta = data.emp;
      });
  };
});
```

// Displaying only "BNK" not "GPs"

```
      <tr ng-repeat="x in dta | filter:enteredValue">
                <td>{{x.BNK}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the x object to 'doIt' function in the controller:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in dta | filter:enteredValue">
    <td data-ng-click=doIt(x)>{{x.BNK}}</td>


$scope.doIt = function(x) {

  // because 'GPx' propery name is change between objects 
  // then we need to find the 'GPx' property name inside x: GP1 ?, GP2 ?, ... GPn ?
  var gpRegex = /^GP\d+/;
  var gpPropertyName = null;
  for(var propertyName in x) {
    if (gpRegex.test(propertyName)){
        gpPropertyName = propertyName;
    }
  }

  // if 'GPx' propery exists in x obj then insert its id's to target url
  if (gpPropertyName && x[gpPropertyName]){
    var gp = x[gpPropertyName];
    var gpIds = gp.join(',');
    $scope.targetUrl = 'http://api.abc.com/GetGPs?' + gpPropertyName + '=' + gpIds + &uid=api-key';
    $http.get( $scope.targetUrl )
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.dta = data.emp;
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: Its not working and not letting my previous data to be displayed in angular.

Comment: It is neither showing error nor allowing previous data to be displayed only warning. WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.